# microsoft sql server management

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a problem when I try doing attach to db.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, your database is in a newer format than what your SQL Management Studio supports. Seems like you're trying to restore a SQL 2008 R2 database to SQL 2008 Non-R2. As the following page suggests, you need to install and restore to R2:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/f8f8db38-3c20-45e4-ae8b-4cc097eb7f0d

Comment: To be clear, it's not Management Studio throwing this error, but rather the SQL Express instance.

Comment: You are right, it's the instance of SQL Server that is throwing the error. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

It's happening an incompatibility error. You should probably install the SQL Server R2 or later.